# write a procedure or a query to delete the user and all its related records

Tags: mysql

I have a query, we have a large database and many tables but one thing is quite common in the database tables is the usage of `rfcID`. So we want to delete all the users who have been inactive for last 6 months and they are only free memberships which define the membership in our paypal table and a column field which is membership as 1.

I want to use both actions because there are some records in our database where membership is 1 even the user is  paid member due to some error. i tried writing some script but that is potentially timing out and hanging my mysql server

he code i have is like this

```
DELETE FROM `users`, `comments` 
USING `users`,`comments` 
WHERE `comments`.`rfcID` = `users`.`id` AND users.rfcID NOT IN (select rfcID from paypal);
```

i have 30+ plus which i all need to check for

Answer (score 0):

In these situations where you want to delete a thing and everything related to it, rather than do it manually, you'd use an [`on delete cascade` referential action](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in the schema.

```
create table users (
    id integer primary key auto_increment
);

create table comments (
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    user integer not null,
    foreign key(user) references users(id) on delete cascade,
    comment text not null
);
```

Now when you `delete from users where id = ?` any comments associated with that user will also be deleted.

Just make sure you're using InnoDB tables and `foreign_key_checks` are on.

```
mysql> show variables like 'foreign_key_checks';                                                    +--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+

mysql> select table_name, engine from information_schema.TABLES where table_name in ('users','comments');
+------------+--------+
| table_name | engine |
+------------+--------+
| comments   | InnoDB |
| users      | InnoDB |
+------------+--------+
```

Comment: You could, but you don't have to.

Comment: problem is we do not have cascade, its old database build using bad design

Comment: @Habb I know what old MySQL databases can be like. Could you alter the tables to add foreign keys and reference actions?

Comment: that is going to be really tough

Comment: @Habb Yes, it will be. Look at it this way. You mentioned there's 30+ related tables. You could write a bunch of code to delete from all the related tables, possibly multiple times. Or you can fix the schema once. OTOH changing the schema has global effects that you might not be able to account for. A middle ground might be to write a `delete_user` function which 1) starts a transaction, 2) selects the appropriate `rfcIDs`, 3) deletes them from all related tables (possibly even as separate `delete` queries), 4) commits. Then you can update the schema a table at a time.